# Can I use simply exitcode within test expression (without $?)?

Tags: shell, sh, exit-code, ash

I have to make a conditional in ash, that depends on result of two commands. The problem is one of them returns the result to stdout, the other as exitcode.

Do I have to write

```
 command2
 RET=$?
 if [ `command1` -eq 1 -a $RET -eq 2 ] ; then ...
```

or is there some construct that would let me simply access return code of `command2` within logic of `[ ]` ?

```
 if [ `command1` -eq 1 -a ${{{ command2 }}} -eq 2 ] ; then ...
```

( with `${{{ }}}}` being the magical expression extracting the returncode ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to write:

```
if [ "`command1`" -eq 1 ] && command2
then
  ....
fi
```

Or when you want to check if the exit code is 2 then:

```
if [ "`command1`" -eq 1 ] && { command2 ; [ "$?" = 2 ] ; }
then
  ....
fi
```

Example:

```
$ cat 1.sh
ARG="$1"

command1()
{
  echo 1
}
command2()
{
  return "$ARG"
}

if [ "`command1`" -eq 1 ] && { command2 ; [ "$?" = 2 ] ; }
then
  echo OK
else
  echo FAILED
fi

$ sh 1.sh 2
OK
$ sh 1.sh 3
FAILED
```

Comment: You need to quote like: `[ "\`command1\`" ... ]` otherwise everything will break unless the output splits to exactly one word.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to avoid $?, but I can use the command inside test statement, by adding `;echo $?` at the end.

```
if [ `command1` -eq 1 -a `command2 ; echo $?` -eq 2 ] ; then ...
```